# How to make element appear on hover text?

Tags: html, css

So I have this text that I want to have a link appear over. For example here is an image of what I want to appear : [image]
When I hover on the highlighted text or when I hover on the link I want it to appear but I'm not sure how to go about this. For example I tried something similar but I can't seem to have the hover text seemlessly go with other text :

```
<p class="text">Espresso is coffee brewed by expressing or forcing a small amount of nearly boiling water under pressure through finely ground coffee beans.<span class="span"> Espresso is generally thicker than coffee brewed by other methods, has a higher concentration of suspended and dissolved solids, and has crema on top (a foam with a creamy consistency). <span class="hide" id="hide">Hello</span></span> As a result of the pressurized brewing process, the flavors and chemicals in a typical cup of espresso are very concentrated. Espresso is also the base for other drinks such as a caffè latte, cappuccino, caffè macchiato, caffè mocha, flat white, or caffè Americano. Espresso has more caffeine per unit volume than most coffee beverages, but because the usual serving size is much smaller, the total caffeine content is less than a mug of standard brewed coffee, contrary to a common belief.[2] Although the actual caffeine content of any coffee drink varies by size, bean origin, roast method and other factors, the caffeine content of typical servings of espresso vs. drip brew are 120 to 170 mg[3] vs. 150 to 200 mg.[4][5]</p>
```

And here is the css :

```
.span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 16, 16, 0.25);
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}



.hide {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #2B2424;
  color: #339CD8;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:10px;
}

.span:hover > .hide {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

Now this only makes the item appear when the text is hovered over it, but I want the bubble to always appear in the same place relative to the text. Now this works if I switch the span tags with p tags. But If I do that, the text won't stick with all the other text around it. It does this: [image]
Now I'm not sure what to do. Thanks in advance!! (Also I hate css so much)

Answer (score 1):

i am sorry before, i want to help but 50%. I just give you some example about the dialog. sorry i cannot helpfully

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```